# mongoose populate array with aggregate and keep format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following model which has an array of categories with consists of objects with category: ObjectId and options: [ObjectId, ObjectId].

```
const page = new Schema({
   "categories":[
      {
         "category":{
            "type":"Schema.Types.ObjectId",
            "ref":"Category",
            "_id":false,
            "index":true
         },
         "options":[
            {
               "type":"Schema.Types.ObjectId",
               "ref":"CategoryOptions",
               "_id":false,
               "index":true
            }
         ],
         "_id":false
      }
   ]
})
```

I am trying to populate the fields while using the .aggregate method. However, somehow I cant get it work without losing the overall structure.
My output should look like this in the end:

```
[
   {
      "category":{
         "_id":"ObjectId",
         "name":"name of category"
      },
      "options":[
         {
            "_id":"ObjectId",
            "name":"name of options"
         },
         {
            "_id":"ObjectId",
            "name":"name of options"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

My current aggregate looks like this:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'categories',
      localField: 'categories.category',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'categories',
      pipeline: [
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'categoryoptions',
            localField: 'options',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'options'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

However this does not work since it only populates the category and flattens the structure to categories: [...results]

Any idea how I could simply populate the values without not losing the given strucutre?

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

```
{
        $unwind: {
          path: '$categories'
        }
      }, {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'categories',
          localField: 'categories.category',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'categoryObjects.category'
        }
      }, {
        $set: {
          categoryObjects: {
            category: {
              $first: '$categoryObjects.category'
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'categoryoptions',
          localField: 'categories.options',
          foreignField: '_id',
          let: {
            cid: '$categories.options'
          },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  $in: [
                    '$_id', '$$cid'
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          as: 'categoryObjects.options'
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          _id: '$_id',
          categories: {
            $push: '$categoryObjects'
          },
         __v: {
            $first: '$__v'
          }
        }
      }
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and have researched as for now you cannot use `$lookup` inside another `$lookup`. The issue with the rest of your query that is mongodb overwrites your existing `categories` field which is present in DB with your `$lookup` result you have written like `as: 'categories',` because of the same name. The original `options` array with ObjectIds is also overwritten. You have to break your aggregation into 2 `$lookup` and then use `$project` aggregation to get your desired structure like this:

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'categories',
      'localField': 'categories.category',
      'foreignField': '_id',
      'as': 'categories_temp'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'options',
      'localField': 'categories.options',
      'foreignField': '_id',
      'as': 'options_temp'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'categories.category': '$categories_temp',
      'categories.options': '$options_temp'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I just tested it. However it's not working like you suggested. I figured out a solution already and updated my question. Please have a look at it.